# Is it possible to run a python script in R shiny

Tags: python, r, shiny

I have some data sets that are in a weird format and have written some python scripts to convert to csv format to use in R.  Is it possible to call the python scripts in an R shiny app?

Comment: I think the answer is yes. You can use `system` to run python scripts. Alternately, you might be able to make use of `rpy2` to persist values across the python and R sessions.

Answer (score 12):

Here is a minimal Shiny app that makes use of `rPython` to execute python calls.

```
library(shiny)
library(rPython)

ui = bootstrapPage(
  sliderInput('x', 'Set x', 0, 10, 5),
  verbatimTextOutput('out1')
)

server = function(input, output, session){
  output$out1 <- renderPrint({
    python.call("len", 1:input$x)
  })
}

runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```

Comment: Thanks!  Do you know if there is an way to install for R 3.1.0?

Comment: Will this work after you publish the app online to shinyapps.io? See related question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32829995/rpython-package-fails-with-r-shiny

Answer (score 3):

I know the topic is close but now you can make shinyApp with python using `reticulate`.

This is a minimalist example.

```
library(reticulate)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  plotOutput(outputId = "plot01")
)

server <- function(input, output){

  # Import module
  plt <- import("matplotlib.pyplot")

  output$plot01 <- renderPlot({
    plt$plot(1:10)
    plt$show()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```