# rPython package fails to install on R Shiny shinyapps.io

Tags: python, r, shiny

Do the shinyapps.io servers not have python installed? Because the package [rPython](http://rpython.r-forge.r-project.org/) fails to install and it needs python installed. I find it odd if the answer is no because RStudio itself has [python support](http://www.r-bloggers.com/controlling-rstudio-python-child-processes/).

Will the shinyapps.io servers ever have python support or is there a workaround? I'd like my published shiny app to call a python script.

Below the installation of rPython on shinyapps.io fails even though it installed and ran fine when done locally (I have python installed obviously).

```
 rsconnect::showLogs("/home/cornelis/Documents/R Shiny/BrainImageAnalyzer")
    2015-09-28T19:32:32.126565+00:00 shinyapps[61711]:     find, fix
    2015-09-28T19:32:32.126567+00:00 shinyapps[61711]:
    2015-09-28T19:32:32.131509+00:00 shinyapps[61711]:
    2015-09-28T19:32:32.131506+00:00 shinyapps[61711]:
    2015-09-28T19:32:32.131507+00:00 shinyapps[61711]:     sum
    2015-09-28T19:32:34.974927+00:00 shinyapps[61711]: Note: the specification for S3 class “AsIs” in package ‘jsonlite’ seems equivalent to one from package ‘RJSONIO’: not turning on duplicate class definitions for this class.
    2015-09-28T19:32:35.010367+00:00 shinyapps[61711]: Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
    2015-09-28T19:32:35.010369+00:00 shinyapps[61711]: (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
    2015-09-28T19:32:35.011193+00:00 shinyapps[61711]: Warning in install.packages("rPython") :
    2015-09-28T19:32:35.011195+00:00 shinyapps[61711]:   'lib = "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library"' is not writable
    2015-09-28T19:32:35.012074+00:00 shinyapps[61711]: Error in install.packages("rPython") : unable to install packages ...
```

related: [Is it possible to run a python script in R shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24901021/is-it-possible-to-run-a-python-script-in-r-shiny)

Comment: I guess that `python` is not installed in `shinyapps.io`..

Comment: But I used the rPython package: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rPython/index.html

Comment: This package permits calls to Python from R, so it assumes that you have python already installed...

Comment: Yes I do. It runs locally on my machine. The program crashes after I publish it online and then it doesn't want to run from the browser

Comment: got the memo from the downvote. Question amended drastically. Got rid of bonus info and honed in on what is actually causing the problem now that it has been found.

Comment: Once you publish it online what matters is whether the webserver has python installed (and available to you), not whether your personal computer has python.

Comment: Question amended even further

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, on shinyapps.io, python is installed, but that does not mean rPython works correctly, or that you will be able to execute your script (depending on what python packages you require).

While python itself may work we don't install scipy/numpy nor do we support installing custom python packages.

Comment: oh that's too bad... Do you plan to add this functionality soon? I'm always willing to translate my Python routines to R, but sometimes it's just not possible because there are some functions in Python that just do not exist in R (like heap functions from the heapq module). So the only solution would be to call my Python routines in my Shiny app... I love Shiny by the way many thanks for this amazing package

Comment: We've discussed adding additional support for python in the past, so its something we're open to, but its not our our roadmap currently.

Comment: Is the installation of popular Python packages still unsupported on shinyapps.io?