# Error occuring when using "rPython" package in R

Tags: python, r, python-2.7, twitter

I've installed all necessary headers and libraries (python-dev) needed for running python script in R environment. I'm running on Ubuntu 14.04 and it has python 2.7 built in it. Properly installed "rPython" package too (which required some python libraries to be installed). **The very same Python Script works fine in Python Environment. But it throws the following error when trying to run in R:**

```
> library(rPython)
> python.load("twitter-geo-search.py", get.exception = TRUE)
Error in python.exec(code, get.exception) : name 'Twitter' is not defined
```

This is the Python Script:

```
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------
# twitter-search-geo
#  - performs a search for tweets close to New Cross, and outputs
#    them to a CSV file.
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------

from twitter import *

import sys
import csv

query = "#TheRevenant"
latitude = 39.0997  # geographical centre of search
longitude = -94.5783    # geographical centre of search
max_range = 1467            # search range in kilometres
num_results = 1500      # minimum results to obtain
outfile = "output.csv"

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------
# load our API credentials 
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------
config = {}
execfile("config.py", config)

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------
# create twitter API object
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------

# Showing error from the below line:

twitter = Twitter(
                auth = OAuth(config["access_key"], config["access_secret"], config["consumer_key"], config["consumer_secret"]))

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------
# open a file to write (mode "w"), and create a CSV writer object
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------
csvfile = file(outfile, "w")
csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------
# add headings to our CSV file
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------
row = [ "user", "text", "latitude", "longitude" ]
csvwriter.writerow(row)

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------
# the twitter API only allows us to query up to 100 tweets at a time.
# to search for more, we will break our search up into 10 "pages", each
# of which will include 100 matching tweets.
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------
result_count = 0
last_id = None
while result_count <  num_results:
    #-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    # perform a search based on latitude and longitude
    # twitter API docs: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/search
    #-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    query = twitter.search.tweets(q = "", geocode = "%f,%f,%dkm" % (latitude, longitude, max_range), count = 100, max_id = last_id)

    for result in query["statuses"]:
        #-----------------------------------------------------------------------
        # only process a result if it has a geolocation
        #-----------------------------------------------------------------------
        if result["geo"]:
            user = result["user"]["screen_name"]
            text = result["text"]
            text = text.encode('ascii', 'replace')
            latitude = result["geo"]["coordinates"][0]
            longitude = result["geo"]["coordinates"][1]

            # now write this row to our CSV file
            row = [ user, text, latitude, longitude ]
            csvwriter.writerow(row)
            result_count += 1
        last_id = result["id"]

    #-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    # let the user know where we're up to
    #-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    print "got %d results" % result_count

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------
# we're all finished, clean up and go home.
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------
csvfile.close()

print "written to %s" % outfile
```

Have also installed the required "twitter" package in Python too (which is why it didn't show error in Python Environment). Don't know why R behaves like this even after that.

Python Script used from GitHub. Link [here](https://github.com/ideoforms/python-twitter-examples/blob/master/twitter-search-geo.py).

Comment: it looks like `python.load` is intended to store a python function to be called via `python.call`. If you are just creating a csv file via python and want to kick off that process in R, I usually use `system("python file.py")` to do it.

Comment: @Forge Yes! I did.

Comment: @cory Thanks! That worked like a charm. Does `system()` function come under "rPython" package or is that a general function() which needs no library to be imported? Does `system("python file.py")` work well under Shiny apps shinyapps.io ?

Comment: No, `system` is in the `base` package. I doubt it will work with shinyapps.io since it could be used to run arbitrary code on their server.

Comment: Maybe you could run that code locally to update a csv file located in dropbox or something. That may be one way to get data to a shinyapps.io app

Comment: All the code have to run at a time. I don't think running the python code seperately will help me out @cory Because, once the end user enters what he needs & clicks, all the code have to be processed at a time and results should be out. I cannot run Python Script individually at that time.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure if you are going to be able to count on somebody else's free server and service having `python` and the required `python` packages to make this run. You might get lucky, I guess. It's probably best to look at their documentation to see if there's any information there.

Comment: @cory Check this post on StackOverFlow: [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32829995/rpython-package-fails-to-install-on-r-shiny-shinyapps-io?rq=1) Think there might be a possibility to use this kind of base package code.

Comment: No, it's not showing. When I execute `library(rPython)`, it simply executes. It's not showing `Loading required package: RJSONIO` Where have I gone wrong? Does this mean I haven't properly setup the `'rPython'` package? @Forge

Comment: You'd have to implement the `twitter` package functionality without loading a third party package, which it seems like is not possible. So, why not just use the `twitteR` package for `R` or write whatever you need in `R` and leave `python` altogether?

Comment: That's because functions() in twitteR to retrieve with geocode not working well. It's not retrieving more no of tweets with geocode for my tweet viz. But this python code works pretty well. That's why @cory